# How to check if value is null or not in F#

Tags: f#

Using this code as an example, how can I check if input is null or not? Similar code is throwing nullreference exception

```
let private Method ( str:string) : string = 
    let a = str
    a.[a.Length-1]
```

Comment: Use the isNull function.

Comment: Resolved with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Although `isNull` is a super simple answer and perfectly valid I thought it would be fun to play with a few others because F# is fun :)

First let us setup a little function to quickly test the results

```
open System

let test f a = 
    try 
        printfn "Input %A, output %A" a (f a)
        printfn "Input %A, output %A" "" (f "")
        printfn "Input %A, output %A" null (f null)
    with
    | :? Exception as ex -> printfn "%s" ex.Message
```

Our first function is just to establish a baseline.
**Throws an exception**

```
//string -> string
let getLast1 ( s:string) : string = s.[s.Length-1] |> string

printfn "=== getLast1 ==="
test getLast1 "bing"
```

> === getLast1 ===
>   Input "bing", output "g"
>   Index was outside the bounds of the array.

The next one checks the value using an `if` and returns an empty string if not a valid value.
**Returns empty string**

```
//string -> string
let getLast2 ( s:string) : string = 
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty s) then "" 
    else s.[s.Length-1] |> string

printfn "=== getLast2 ==="
test getLast2 "bing"
```

> === getLast2 ===
>   Input "bing", output "g"
>   Input "", output ""
>   Input , output ""

We are at least getting all paths executing now.

Let's try a more functional approach:
**Returns `option` using pattern matching**

```
//string -> string option
let getLast3 (s:string) =
    match s with
    | null -> None
    | _ ->
        match (s.ToCharArray()) with
        | [||] -> None
        | [|x|] -> Some x
        | xs -> Array.tryLast xs
    |> Option.map string

printfn "=== getLast3 ==="
test getLast3 "bing"
```

> === getLast3 ===
>   Input "bing", output Some "g"
>   Input "", output <null>  //note that <null> is actually `None` here.
>   Input <null>, output <null>  //note that <null> is actually `None` here.

That works but it is not the easiest function to read. It isn't too bad but what if we tried to break it down.

**Composed function**

```
//'a -> 'a option
let sanitize x = if (isNull x) then None else Some(x)
//string -> char[]
let toCharArray (s:string) = s.ToCharArray()
//'a[] option -> 'a option
let last xs = 
    xs |> Option.map Array.tryLast //tryLast returns an 'a option
    |> Option.flatten // turns 'a option option to a' option
```

Now that we have the building blocks we can build up our new last function:

```
//string -> string option
let getLast4 s =
    s |> sanitize
    |> Option.map toCharArray 
    |> last
    |> Option.map string

printfn "=== getLast4 ==="
test getLast4 "bing"
```

> === getLast4 ===
>   Input "bing", output Some "g"
>   Input "", output <null>  //note that <null> is actually `None` here.
>   Input , output <null>  //note that <null> is actually `None` here.

To be honest `getLast2` is probably fine. If I found myself checking for an empty string I would prefer returning `Some` or `None` from the `if`. I just wanted to show how to move away from `null` and toward using the built in `Array` functions.